# is HTML designed to be static?

Tags: html

I was often said that rule : *"HTML is static"*; in other words : HTML code is not intended to be modified locally, except when you use JavaScript or other languages.

However, with HTML5 specifications, there are some exceptions to that [supposed to be] rule. For example, there is the [**contenteditable** attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/editing.html#contenteditable).

So my questions are : Does this rule exist officially (from experts) ? And why this rule ? Is this so bad to break that rule ?

I ask these questions because I am developing a JavaScript framework. It lets the developers using HTML attributes to modify the page content on user actions (click, etc.). But when I discussed the principle with some developers, saying that it is a wrong idea by quoting that rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% positive, but I can't find anything in the W3 specification (the official rule book) that says HTML *must* be static.

Answer (score 2):

It's an observation rather than a rule. Even with content editable I think it is still static.

Otherwise you could have said the same about a textarea or a textfield. You can change the content of those, but everytime you go to the page the page would still be the same (read static). Also there will be no other content on the page when there are some conditions met.

> But when I discussed the principle with some developers, saying that it is a wrong idea by quoting that rule.

Again it isn't a rule, but an observation, plain HTML **is** static.

Comment: with contenteditable, the HTML content is really modified : http://jsfiddle.net/3vaZm/, at the contrary of textarea markup (only the value is modified, not the inner HTML). And that is the only exception I know.
Thank you for giving your point of you.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how big are your changes... if you're making core changes with the JS, it might not be a good idea, SEO-wise.

But I also haven't heard that rule officially.